# how to write Instead of update? - Trigger

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table `A` and there is a column name `COL_A`.

I want that if someone change the value, lets say from `1` to `'X'` (not costant) that the trigger will change it back from `'X'` to `1`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve exactly? triggers come at a cost

Comment: To have a cell with some value that I don't want it to get change. But in the initial it doesn't required to have the value I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not support changing the `new` column values.
The only way to change a column in a trigger would be to run an `UPDATE` command,
but that would run the trigger again.

What you can do is to prevent changing the column in the first place:

```
CREATE TRIGGER IF NOT EXISTS prevent_col_a_change
BEFORE UPDATE OF col_a ON a
BEGIN
    SELECT RAISE(ABORT, 'COL_A must not be changed');
END;
```

Answer (score -1):

UPDATE trigger is a good solution for your case. Just set old value to the new value, that will lead to behaviour you want.

For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER orders_before_update
BEFORE UPDATE
  ON orders
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  :new.CreatedAt:= :old.CreatedAt;
END;
```

Comment: This is not valid SQLite syntax.